# Possible to use same database for mapnik and pgRouting?

Tags: pgrouting, mapnik

I am already running an OGCServer (mapnik) with an postgis database.

I want to also run pgRouting on preferably the same database, so that I do not have to maintain two separate databases.

I understand that pgRouting adds/changes some requirement to the data model. My question is basically - does it change the requirements in an incompatible way, or does it just add requirement.

(As you might guess; i'm still quite a newbie at pgRouting)

Comment: no it adds it's own fields it is not taking away anything, but test in a dev environment to make sure your happy with the result before applying it to your current db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to add some fields to fulfill pgRouting's requirements but that should not break compatibility with your existing system. 
In general, pgRouting's data model is very flexible because it is based on SQL statements rather than a certain table layout.

Depending on the network data you have, you can probably use the routing functions immediately on your existing data. If your network lacks any of the necessary fields, pgRouting comes with a series of helper functions that can assist you with e.g. assigning node/vertex ids.

As @Mapperz already said, you should still try it in a test environment first but I wouldn't expect any problems.